# Background images will not show on bootstrap carousel

Tags: carousel

I can not seem to get the background images to work on the carousel. Everything else seems to be working but I cannot get the those to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

This is where I have place the css in order to set the background size and what image I plan to use for each slide. I have checked and rechecked to make sure the path to the image is correct and it is 100 percent.

```
<style type="text/css">
        .slide1{
            background-image: url('images/image01.jpg');
            height: 500px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .slide2{
            background-image: url('images/image02.jpg');
            height: 500px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .slide3{
            background-image: url('images/image03.jpg');
            height: 500px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
        }

    </style>
</head>
    <body>

        <div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> </li >
                <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"> </li>
                <li data-target ="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2"> </li>
            </ol >
```

And here is where I used the classes that connect to the specific slides. It seems to me like I have the code correctly typed, but still can't seem to figure out why the images will not show.

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active" >
                    <div class ="slide1"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="slide2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="slide3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"> </span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get them to work by setting the height and width of the div (to 100% in my case). It seems like maybe if there is nothing included in the carousel-item, its default size is 0 so the background image is not visible.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I applied the background directly to the carousel-item div, but if you added a `width:` to your existing slide1, etc. classes, it might work as well.

```
.carousel-item {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active slide1" >

    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
 .slide1{
     background-image: url('images/image01.jpg');
     height: 500px;
     width: _____;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
 }
```